# How do I add my own HTML tag to this PHP code (array)

Tags: php, html, arrays, drupal

Can you please advise how do I add my own HTML tag to the part of PHP code?  I am talking about part "***This part need HTML tag***".

```
<div id="downbarek2">
    <?php
        $vid = 59;
        function termSort($a, $b) {return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);}

        $terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);   usort ($terms,'termSort');

        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            if ($term->depth == 1) {  
                print  "" .l( "This part need HTML tag " .$term->name,'taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid, array('title' => $term->name)). "";
            } 
        }  
    ?>
</div>
```

So, my question is: how can I extend this part of HTML tag, such as...

```
print  "" .l( "<b>This text need HTML tag</b> " .$term->name,'taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid, array('title' => $term->name)). "";
```

Comment: I don't think your question is too clear. What do you mean by **extending HTML tag**. The text you are referring to already has the bold tags in it. Can you give an example of what you want the text to look like?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it already works this way..

Comment: Your synthax is a mess, why are you appending `""` to the beginning and to the end? `""` is a empty string, if you have nothing to add then just add nothing.

Comment: ok, can you give me an example of how to modify the above PHP code so that only the text "This text need HTML tag" was wrapped by tags <b></ b>?

Comment: Could you please explain why are you using `.l()`?

Comment: I'm not a PHP programmer. This is a Drupal function to extract terms. Everything works fine, I just need above text (this: This part need HTML tag) wrap by HTML tag.

Answer (score 2):

In drupal, to achieve this by seting array('html' => TRUE)

```
print  l( t("<b>This text need HTML tag</b> " .$term->name,'taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid), array('attributes' => array('title' => $term->name, ), 'html' => TRUE) );
```

Reference: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7

Comment: when i use your code, i get above error: 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in includes/common.inc(1743) : eval()'d code on line 20

Comment: ups, now i get only errors. First 1 is: warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in includes/common.inc on line 964.                      warning: strtr() [function.strtr]: The second argument is not an array in includes/common.inc on line 981.

Comment: check print_r($terms) before foreach

Comment: IDK what wrong, i get only errors like: warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in filter.module on line 1233. OR    htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in bootstrap.inc on line 860. @Tamil